# How to load Field from torchtext.data?

Tags: pytorch, text-mining, torchtext

I have installed torchtext v 0.14.1. I am on Windows. I tried to load Field but I got the following error. Can anybody help me fix it?

```
from torchtext.data import Field

ImportError: cannot import name 'Field' from 'torchtext.data' (C:\Users\X\anaconda3\envs\torch-env\lib\site-packages\torchtext\data\__init__.py)
```